# google sheets, apps script parsehtml error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

this is the complete code,

```
function extractData() {
  var url = "https://www.theopenalliance.com/teams/2023/";
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var data = parseHtml(html);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clearContents();
  if (data.length > 0) {
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        if (data[i][j].indexOf("http") === 0) {
          var button = sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).attachButton({
            text: "Link",
            url: data[i][j]
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function parseHtml(html) {
  var startIndex = html.indexOf("<tbody>");
  var endIndex = html.indexOf("</tbody>");
  var table = html.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
  var rows = table.split("<tr>");
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].split("<td");
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 1; j < cells.length; j++) {
      var cell = cells[j];
      var linkStartIndex = cell.indexOf("href=");
      if (linkStartIndex !== -1) {
        var linkEndIndex = cell.indexOf("class");
        var link = cell.substring(linkStartIndex + 6, linkEndIndex - 2);
        row.push(link);
      } else {
        row.push(cell.substring(cell.indexOf(">") + 1, cell.indexOf("</td>")));
      }
    }
    data.push(row);
  }
  return data;
}
```

however function `parseHtml(html)` gives an error with this line

```
var startIndex = html.indexOf("<tbody>");
```

Anyone has any suggestions? i'm trying to copy and paste tables from the link to a google sheets.

i expected to see every teams numbers and other values (Public links, location etc) in google sheets but nothing shows up. Also i was expecting to see buttons that had links attached to them if the buttons exists, such as github, photos etc. Please check the link and im sure you will have a better idea of im trying to tell. Also please help me fix the code, if possible, copy and edit the code than repost it, i would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Typically it's a lot easier to solve errors if you tell what the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about using Sheets API? Because I thought that the HTML parser of Sheets API is useful for your situation. When Sheets API is used for your URL, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  const url = "https://www.theopenalliance.com/teams/2023/"; // This is from your script.

  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const table = html.match(/<table[\s\S\w]+?<\/table>/);
  if (!table) {
    throw new Error("Table was not found.");
  }
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet().clearContents();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const requests = { requests: [{ pasteData: { html: true, data: table[0], coordinate: { sheetId: sheet.getSheetId() } } }] };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(requests, ss.getId());
}
```

- When this script is run, a table is retrieved from the URL and put it into the active sheet.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)

Comment: you literally are my hero, please tell me if there is any way to rate your account so you will show higher in StackOverflow. If there is none, take my word for 5 stars.

Comment: @mollinas Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, I appreciate your comment. Thank you, too.